# Laravel table pivot nomenclature

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a menu table, a group menu and a pivot table for this table.

```
menus
menu_groups
menu_menu_group or menu_group_menu?
```

Is correct this nomenclature?

Thanks!

Comment: You can effectively use whatever names you want, as long as you tell Laravel the table names (a) in the model (using protected $table = "whatever") and in the relationship as one of the parameters passed to the closure of the hasManyThrough() (or whatever relationship you're using).

Comment: @GilesBennett It's right that you can _modify_ the table names by doing this but maybe they want to follow Laravel's default nomenclature.

Comment: @shaedrich Yes, the correct nomenclature for best practice.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet but both should be possible and since Laravel is fairly smart it should get it either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is based on the class names of the models. It gets the class basenames (class name) of each Model and converts them to snake case:

```
Str::snake(class_basename($modelInstance));
```

After it gets an array of the 2 names then it calls `sort`:

```
sort($segments);
```

Then it `implode`s that array, joining it by an underscore, and makes sure its lowercase:

```
return strtolower(implode('_', $segments));
```

So if your classes are `Menu` and `MenuGroup` then the pivot by convention would be: `menu_menu_group`.

Answer (score -1):

The correct name based on Laravel models will be **menu_menu_groups**